# Python Flask HTML form input conversion to hexadecimal keeping number entered

Tags: python, html, flask, type-conversion

To start, yes I am a total noob. And thank you for your feedback!

I am hoping to submit a number to a form input that is a hexadecimal number that then gets used in a low level C function as the same hexadecimal number. What is happening is that the number I enter then gets converted to hexadecimal from decimal. If I type the required hexadecimal number in decimal form it will do what I want. But it would be nice to not have to figure out the decimal form first.

C functions are API library and that is all working. My task is to setup a Flask based server to show some functionality of the C library on a SBC.

Here is some code that works on its own:

## testing.py

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python

from C_LIB import *

from ctypes import *

import ctypes.util

from sys import platform

libc=CDLL("c_lib.so",mode=RTLD_GLOBAL)

open = libc.Open()

regoffset = 0x63

hexvalue = 0x69

curValue = c_int()

libc.WriteRegister(regoffset, hexvalue)

print (type(hexvalue))

print (hexvalue)

libc.ReadRegister(regoffset, byref(curValue))

curValue = curValue.value

print ( '{:02X}'.format(curValue))`
```

## flask_app.py  (just the route)

```
`@app.route("/fpga", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def fpga():

    if request.method == 'GET':

        regoffset = 0

        curValue = 0

    if request.method == 'POST':

        regoffset = request.form.get('reg_offset', type=int)

        hexvalue = request.form.get('hex_value', type=int)

// I have tried type=str and no type and other conversions following this get 

        print (type(hexvalue))

        print ('hello there!', hexvalue)

        print (type(hexvalue))

        if regoffset == None:

            regoffset = 0

        curValue=c_char()

        libc.ReadRegister(regoffset, byref(curValue))

        curValue = curValue.value

        if hexvalue != None:

            libc.WriteRegister(regoffset, hexvalue)`
# this c function will convert integers ## to a hex value or will take a direct hex value as 0x##. Cannot change this function

    return render_template('testfpga.html',

          NameProduct2=NameProduct2,

          NameProduct1=NameProduct1,

          regoffset=hex(regoffset),

          curValue=getRegValue(regoffset, curValue))
```

## testfpga.html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="Python Web App" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/stylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.7.1.js') }}"></script>

    <title>FPGA stuff</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>FPGA Read/Write Commands</h1>

    <div style="color:red"><strong> WARNING!! LOW LEVEL COMMANDS CAN BE DANGEROUS TO THE SBC IF NOT USED CORRECTLY!!>

<form method="post" action="{{url_for('fpga')}}">
    <label for="reg_offset"> Register Offset (decimal): </label>
    <input type="text" name="reg_offset" placeholder="00" id="reg_offset"></input>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Get Value</button></br>
    <label for="hex_value"> New Value (hex): </label>
    <input type="text" name="hex_value" placeholder="0x00" id="hex_value"> </input>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Set Value</button>
</form>

    <h2> {{ NameProduct1 }} register {{ regoffset }} is {{ curValue }} </h2>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: You are telling `request` to convert the value to an integer.  Don't do that.  Fetch the values as strings, and do `hexvalue = int(hexvalue, 16)`.  And your print statement is always going to print the decimal value.  That's fine.  Your C code doesn't want hex values.  It wants binary.  It has no clue how that number began its life.

Comment: Oh bless you @Tim Roberts! I definitely experimented around this answer but must have continued to have another conversion in the way somewhere. This was it!